# There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406) for Spring @RestController, spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I'm trying to return xml from my @RestController method -

```
@RestController
public class MCSController {
.
.
@RequestMapping(value = "/encoders", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<EncoderVO> getEncoders() {

    List<EncoderVO> encoders = null;
    try {
        encoders = infoService.listEncoders();
    } catch (MCSException e) {
        logger.error("Error in listing encoders : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return encoders;
}
```

Here is my EncoderVO.java -

```
@XmlRootElement
public class EncoderVO {

@XmlElement
private Long id;

@XmlElement
private String name;

@XmlElement
private Boolean flagActive;

public EncoderVO() {
}

public EncoderVO(Long id, String name, Boolean flagActive) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.flagActive = flagActive;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Boolean getFlagActive() {
    return flagActive;
}

public void setFlagActive(Boolean flagActive) {
    this.flagActive = flagActive;
}

}
```

This is my pom.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>mcs</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <aws.sdk-version>1.9.1</aws.sdk-version>
    <liquibase.version>3.3.0</liquibase.version>
</properties>

<!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aws SDK Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.sdk-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.sdk-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.sdk-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.sdk-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-datapipeline</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.sdk-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>


        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudfront</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.sdk-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Below is my Application class -

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class, LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.ott.mcs" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableJms
@EntityScan("com.test.ott.mcs.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.ott.mcs.repository")
    public class MCSApplication {

    @Bean
    JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        // A core poll size of 3 threads and a maximum pool size of 10 threads
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        return factory;
    }

    // Using factory pattern with spring annotation
    @Bean
    public FactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean() {
        ServiceLocatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setServiceLocatorInterface(EncodingAPIFactory.class);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(MCSApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I hit the url /encoders in browser, i get the below error -

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406). Could
>   not find acceptable representation

The jackson related jars in my calsspath are -

- jackson-core-asl : 1.9.13
- jackson-jaxrs : 1.9.13
- jackson-mapper-asl : 1.9.13
- jackson-annotations : 2.6.3
- jackson-core : 2.6.3
- jackson-module-jaxb-annotations : 2.2.3
- jackson-jaxrs-json-provider : 2.2.3
- jackson-jaxrs-base : 2.5.4
- jackson-databind : 2.6.3

So, I have **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** in my classpath.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more info? The request that you send to this endpoint (curl).

Comment: This is a simple get request that I hit on an application running on my localhost (tomcat) server.  -  '**http:/localhost:8080/encoders**'

Comment: Jackson1 isn't supported and are you sure the jackson 2 versions are present as you have excluded them (why?). Also a `List<EncoderVo>` isn't valid for XML as that isn't an XML type, so that would fail.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have jackson2 in my dependencies , which I'm getting from another local module which I have removed from pom while posting this question. That's why the exclusion. 
Yes, the list is not a xml type and probably that's the reason it is failing. How can I make it work with a `List<EncoderVo>`? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot. You would have to wrap it in an `EnvoderVos` object which in turn has the list. You need to return an XML object else the marshaller cannot understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution that will work out-of-the-box, similarly to JAX-RS but with a bit worse output. The solution uses jackson-dataformat-xml. Add dependency to your project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Response will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
   <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>testEncoder1</name>
      <flagActive>true</flagActive>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>testEncoder2</name>
      <flagActive>true</flagActive>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>3</id>
      <name>testEncoder3</name>
      <flagActive>true</flagActive>
   </item>
</List>
```

For further details please look at [Spring MVC Way (jackson-dataformat-xml)](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/04/jax-rs-2x-vs-spring-mvc-returning-xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

try

`http://localhost:8080/mcs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/encoders`.

mcs is the name of the application and 
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT the version.

If it doesn't works you have to add a global path into the RequestController. Something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/mcs")
public class MCSController {
.
.
@RequestMapping(value = "/encoders", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<EncoderVO> getEncoders() {
```

and this request:

`http://localhost:8080/mcs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mcs/encoders`

i hope it helps you.

Cheers

Comment: The thing is I'm able to get logs in my controller methods and it is hitting the backend and fetching the list, but while converting the list to XML, this is giving 406.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependecy in you POM.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.8.8</version>
```

problem is with version of this jar. so please try out this solution